# Asp.Net Core + Angular = Protect Api without login

Tags: .net, angular, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a .net core + angular application that doesn't have login functionality.
I don't need login but i want to have an "admin panel" type functionality.

For example i want to add posts to my site.

I understand that i can't use api / addpost / myPassword or whatever complex string known only by me
because there are ways to see that.
How i can protect my api without implementing register/ login functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me try to understand this by rephrasing your question. You want to be able to protect your service endpoint, so it can't be accessed outside your application, but you don't want to implement login/register functionality? Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, i want to be the only person that can add posts for example. And i don't want to implement register/login functionality only for that.  It will be nice if you could access that service from outside the application ( maybe i will hire a moderator that can add posts...so i can give him the "keys" to acces only that api, but for now it's ok to not be accesed outside the application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things you can do.

The easiest thing you can do is create a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` that will validate your service call before entering your API controller method.

I've used a `Guid` value here, but you can use anything.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class CustomValidateRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
            var headerValue = actionContext.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Key == "validation-value").Value?.FirstOrDefault();
            Guid guidValidationValue;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue ) && !Guid.TryParse(headerValue , out guidValidationValue))
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

You will add this custom attribute to your `AddPost` method in your API controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomValidateRequest]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddPost...//rest of your code
```

In your service on the client side, you will have to add this header value to headers. Something like:

```
addPosts(url, data) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('validation-value', 'your-guid-value-or-something-else');
    return this.http.post(url, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }
```

For a more complicated and more secure options, you can check out how to implement Anti-Forgery Middleware [here](http://fiyazhasan.me/angularjs-anti-forgery-with-asp-net-core/) and [here](https://timdows.com/projects/preventing-csrf-in-asp-net-core-combined-with-angularjs/).

Comment: I used ActionExecutingContext for the .net function ( HttpActionContext didn't work. I'm using .net core 2.0, probably that's why. ) And in the angular service i get the "password" from local storage.  Your solution helped me, thanks!